# Can anyone please explain how does this work?

Tags: python, string

Suppose I declare a string and if I want to print '-1' index to '5' index; I get an answer which I do not expect. Just wanted to know how the string traverses in this case

```py
>>> str = 'qwerty'
>>> str[-1:5]
''
>>> str[-1:6]
'y'
```

Comment: pls use some other name for the variable name as `str` is a function

Answer (score 2):

I've name the string x to avoid the name conflict with str.

```
x = "qwerty"
```

The -1 denotes the last index of the string, which is 5. From that can you see why your slice results are what they are.

```
x[0:-1] -> x[0:5] -> "qwert"
x[-1:5] -> x[5:5] -> ""
x[-1:6] -> x[5:6] -> "y"
```

The low index is inclusive but the upper index is exclusive. Eg. `x[0:0]` gives you no characters, but `x[0:1]` gives you the 0th index character.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, slicing returns the elements from the starting index till the ending index MINUS ONE. So, if you print `s[-1:5]`, it actually will print from the last index 5 till index 4 (note that this is reverse traversal and until the index step is -1, this is not possible). Hence, you get an empty string.
If you print `s[-1:6]`, on the other hand, you are basically accessing the last index 5 and 6-1, which is 5, again. This is equivalent to `s[5:6]`, which will return the last character `y`.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

because -1 and 5 are the same place

note that table while using the two forms of indexing

[image]

you may read [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/slice.html)   and [extended slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices) on official documentation to understand it more .

### long answer to understand how slicing works in python

`i=0`

`j=1`

`s="qwerty"`

`s[i:j]`

OUTPUT

`q`

it is just  about selecting **from** i index **until before** j index
so to select last letter "y"
it can be done using `i=5` and `j=6` .. note no index of 6 can't be actually used you just specify that you will crop from i=5 and crop only one character `6-5=1`

also consider
there is third argument while slicing

```
s= 'qwerty'
print(s[5:6:1])
```

will give the same

```
y
```

as you slice with start and end as the same with step of 1
you can select from end to start to revrse it by making

```
s= 'qwerty'
print(s[5:-7:-1])
```

OUTPUT

```
ytrewq
```

Comment: Updated it right now